# Markov process: characterize states which cannot arise naturally from a previous state

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

From an old qualifying exam:

> Assume that a particular electric switch has three states: left,
>   middle, and right. Assume that the switch is programmed to follow
>   these instructions at the start of each hour:
>
> - If the switch was pointing to the left for the last hour then it    flips to the right
> - If the switch was pointing to the right for the last hour then it flips either to the left or the middle with 50% probability for each
>     choice.
> - If the switch was pointing to the middle for the last hour then it either stays where is is, or flips to the right (with probability 50%
>     for each choice)
>
> Now assume you initialize a very large number of independently
>   operating switches of this type. Let the vector $s^{[0]}\in
>  \mathbb{R}^3$ denote the distribution of switch states, such that
>   $s_1^{[0]}, s_2^{[0]},s_3^{[0]}$ represent the fraction of the
>   switches in the left, middle, and right states, respectively (note
>   that $s_1^{[0]} + s_2^{[0]} + s_3^{[0]}$ must equal one.
>
> **Problem:** characterize the state distributions that could not have arisen naturally from a previous state distribution.

**My attempt so far:** There is an answer attempt [here](http://math.nyu.edu/student_resources/wwiki/index.php/Linear_Algebra%3a_2009_January%3a_Problem_5#Part_4_Solution) (where it says "part 4 answer") that I do not find satisfactory. All admissible input vectors lie in the region $D$ between the coordinate planes and the triangle $T=\{x+y+z=1\mid x,y,z\geq0\}$. The answer's strategy is to note that the transition matrix $$L = \left(  \begin{matrix} 0&0& 1/2 \\ 0& 1/2 & 1/2 \\ 1 & 1/2 &0 \end{matrix} \right)$$ has one eigenvalue $=1$ and the two other eigenvalues between zero and 1, so repeated applications of $T$ to a vector $v\in D$ will shrink it each time, eventually to $\rho_1v$, where $\rho_1$ projects onto the $1$ eigenspace along the other two eigenspaces. It says that the vectors in between $T$ and the image of $T$ under $L$ could not arise naturally from a previous state, and I agree with this. But there it stops. Surely there are more such vectors? In fact, all the vectors in $$D\setminus \{L^k(T) \mid k\in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$$ cannot arise naturally, right? Can we characterize them more precisely than that?

Answer (score 0):

If $v$ is in $D$, not in $L^2(T)$, but is in $L(T)$, then it is $L(w)$ for some $w$ in $T$, so it does arise naturally from the previous state $w$.

You may be thinking, but you can't trace it any farther back than one iteration, but I think that's all the question is asking for.